# Значения перечисления в switch-case блоке

Tags: java, импорт, enum

У меня есть простое перечисление:

```
package reports.generation;

public enum ReportType {
    CARD_EMISSION_SIMPLE,
    CARD_EMISSION_WITH_STATUS
}
```

Которое я хочу использовать в классе другого пакета. Однако если я пытаюсь ссылаться на значение перечисления в виде `ReportType.CARD_EMISSION_SIMPLE`:

```
package reports.ui.service;

...
import reports.generation.ReportType;

public class BgrdService extends Service<String> {
   class BgrdTask extends Task<String> {
        @Override 
        protected String call() throws Exception {
             try {
                 switch (reportType) {
                    case ReportType.CARD_EMISSION_SIMPLE:
                        System.out.println("CARD_EMISSION_SIMPLE");
                        break;
                    case ReportType.CARD_EMISSION_WITH_STATUS :
                        System.out.println("CARD_EMISSION_WITH_STATUS");
                        break;
                 }          
                 ...
             } catch (Exception ex) {
                 ...
             }    
        }
    }
}
```

Eclipse подчёркивает это значение красным и при наведении мыши выдаёт следующее предупреждение:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и при нажатии на ссылку "Replace with the unqualified enum constant 'CARD_EMISSION_SIMPLE'" заменяет значение `ReportType.CARD_EMISSION_SIMPLE` на `CARD_EMISSION_SIMPLE`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но при этом в импортах ничего не меняется, по-прежнему остаётся только

```
import reports.generation.ReportType;
```

Хотя в других местах, не в операторе `case` можно ссылаться на `CARD_EMISSION_SIMPLE` без `ReportType.` только с помощью статического импорта:

```
import static reports.generation.ReportType.CARD_EMISSION_SIMPLE;

...
         switch (reportType) {
                    case CARD_EMISSION_SIMPLE: 
                        System.out.println(CARD_EMISSION_SIMPLE);
                        break;
...
```

Почему в операторе `case` блока `switch-case` можно ссылаться на `CARD_EMISSION_SIMPLE` без `ReportType.` без статического импорта?

Comment: Дык потому что case это особая консрукция. И если вы перебираете по Enum, то вы в case ветках ничего больше не можете сделать. То есть нельзя написать switch (EnumEntitry) { case "string": Как бы и все. Можно и можно. Почему? ну вот захотели вот так создатели Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

это логично, потому что switch уже "знает" какого типа переменная (reportType), а т.к. других значений кроме как тех что определены в enum она принимать не может (null не в счет), то и квалифицировать константы нет необходимости.